# Can I wash my Logitech K270 wireless keyboard?

Tags: water-damage, logitech-keyboard

I spilled coke on my Logitech K270 keyboard and now a couple of keys, once pressed, take minutes to retract.

The keyboard is touted as spill-proof. Can I pour water to clean it?

Comment: Why would you pour water on it on purpose?

Comment: *Spill-proof* keyboards usually just means that there are channels within the keyboard so that any fluid poured over the keys will tend to run away from the electronics.  It also may mean that certain portions have been sealed to protect them.  Neither of these should be taken as an indicator to intentionally pour more liquid over keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

No!

If spilling coke on it has damaged it - the stupidest thing you can do it put more liquid on it!

Try getting some rubbing alcohol or a cleaning solution on a cotton swab, remove all batteries, keys etc from the keyboard and swab off the coke residue.  The keys can be washed in water as long as they are dried off thoroughly before used again.

"Spill Proof" tends to just mean that if you spill a small amount of liquid on the keyboard, panic and dry it off extremely quickly - it should survive.  As someone who was once stung by this, you'll also find that logitec's warranty terms will tell you that you aren't covered for a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Popping out the keys (just the two of them) and cleaning worked.
Looks like the keys of a keyboard can be popped out safely!

Comment: It depends on the keyboard model. Some don't take kindly to the key caps or even the entire keys being removed.